# Adding trig format = rad to my TikZ axis options causes the y-axis to not show up correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I need to add trig format = rad for a plot to work, but it messes up the y-axis. Try adding a % before it and you'll see what I mean.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    trig format = rad,
    view={0}{90},
    xmax=10, xmin=-10, ymax=10, ymin=-10,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    zticklabels={\empty}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the non-minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    trig format = rad,
    view={0}{90},
    domain=-10:10,
    y domain=-10:10,
    xmax=10, xmin=-10, ymax=10, ymin=-10,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    samples=21,
    zticklabels={\empty}
]
\addplot3 [gray, quiver={u={1},
v={cos(x)},
scale arrows=0.75, every arrow/.append style={-}}] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: why you use so old version of the  `pgfplots` package? Few years is available 1.18!

Comment: I usually use \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}. I was under the impression that 1.19 was newer 1.18 and realize now that I was wrong, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Version 1.19 not existed yet, you declare 1.9 which is realy old. By version 1.11 syntax is quirte improved. I always mark used package version of package that after while is clear which version has been used.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost minimum code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            axis lines=center,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            trig format = rad,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            ymin=-1.5,
            ymax=1.5
            ]
            \addplot[magenta] [domain=-2*pi:2*pi, smooth, line width=3pt] { sin(x)};
            \addlegendentry{\(y=\sin x\)}
            \addplot[cyan] [domain=-2*pi:2*pi, smooth, line width=3pt] { cos(x)};
            \addlegendentry{\(y=\cos x\)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD** to OP request.

Like this:

[image]

New code:

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            trig format = rad,
            view={90}{90},
            xmax=10, xmin=-10, ymax=5, ymin=-5,
            zmin=-1, zmax=1,
            zticklabels={\empty}
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            ymin=-1.5,
            ymax=1.5
            ]
            \addplot[magenta] [domain=-2*pi:2*pi, smooth, line width=3pt] { sin(x)};
            \addlegendentry{\(y=\sin x\)}
            \addplot[cyan] [domain=-2*pi:2*pi, smooth, line width=3pt] { cos(x)};
            \addlegendentry{\(y=\cos x\)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to be working in 3d, do you have any suggestions? I am trying to plot a 3d slope field. I added a non minimal working example to the question

Comment: Sorry, when you change your trig format to rad, you also need to express the viewing angle in terms of radians too! the solution was to replace view={0}{90} with view={0}{pi/2}. I'll give you the answer since you put so much effort in. :)